# Obtener valor JSON desde un nombre de variable dinámico en php

Tags: php, json

Si ejecuto con código directo lo siguiente:

```
echo $json[0]->cespecialp1;
```

Me retorna el valor obtenido desde la base de datos, pero busco que la obtención del valor sea dinámico, porque si no tendría que escribir manualmente todos los valores, por ejemplo:

```
echo $json[0]->cespecialp1;
echo $json[1]->cespecialp2;
echo $json[2]->cespecialp3;
//etc.
```

Estoy haciendo ésto:

```
$json = json_decode( $infoRow->cespecial); //$infoRow trae el json obtenido previamente de una consulta sql

for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
   $puntero = $i-1;
   $evalp = "\$json[$puntero]->cespecialp$i".";";
   echo $evalp.": ".eval( $evalp)."<br>";
}
```

El `echo $evalp.": ".eval( $evalp)."<br>";` me está retornando:

```
$json[0]->cespecialp1;:
$json[1]->cespecialp2;:
$json[2]->cespecialp3;:
$json[3]->cespecialp4;:
$json[4]->cespecialp5;:
```

Que es lo que debería evaluar y luego de los `:` debería entregar el resultado, ya que si escribo cada linea directamente en el código, me entrega el valor almacenado en la base de datos, pero con el `eval` no retorna nada.

Agradeceré la ayuda.
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$json` es un array de objetos, luego puedes iterarlo con un `foreach` y definir el nombre de la propiedad con una variable **sin usar eval!**

Pensemos que `$infoRow->cespecial` se define como:

```
<?php
$infoRow=new stdClass();
$infoRow->cespecial = json_encode([
            ["propiedadp1"=>"valor1"], 
            ["propiedadp2"=>"valor2"], 
            ["propiedadp3"=>"valor3"],
            ["propiedadp4"=>"valor4"],
            ["propiedadp5"=>"valor5"],
    ]);
```

luego el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($infoRow->cespecial);

foreach($json as $index=>$value) {
    $indice=($index+1);
    $propiedad='propiedadp'.$indice;
    printf('$json[%s]->%s : %s; <br>', $index, $propiedad, $json[$index]->$propiedad);
}
```

imprimiría:

Eso imprime:

```
$json[0]->propiedadp1 : valor1;
$json[1]->propiedadp2 : valor2;
$json[2]->propiedadp3 : valor3;
$json[3]->propiedadp4 : valor4;
$json[4]->propiedadp5 : valor5;
```

[Pruébalo aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6d63a9fc37f5b93a79234d4bc2fa7076e64aea2)

Date cuenta que si el valor de `$json[0]->propiedadp1` fuese el texto `"phpinfo()";` el hecho de usar `eval("phpinfo();");` implica ejecutar `phpinfo();` y asumo que no quieres eso. Simplemente **escribe** el contenido, **no lo evalúes**. Evita usar `eval` en lo posible, o sea evítalo siempre.